# R: Is there a function/easy way for erasing spaces in elements of a dataset only in those containing numbers as characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, numbers

Is there a function/easy way for removing all spaces only in elements of dataset that contain numbers (class character)? For example "23 456"

Here's an example of the data:

```
structure(list(`VÝKAZ MYSL 1-01 - SUMÁŘE` = c("Vlastnický vztah k honitbě", 
"1. vlastní", "2. společenstevní", NA, "Způsob využívání honitby", 
"1. ve vlastní režii"), ...2 = c("počet", "1 496", "4 255", "honitba", 
"počet", "751"), ...3 = c(NA, "1 511 605", "5 077 050", NA, NA, 
NA), ...4 = c("ha", NA, NA, NA, "ha", "780 487"), ...5 = c("počet", 
"178", "24", NA, "počet", "137"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, NA, "obora", 
NA, NA), ...7 = c("ha", "41 911", "2 401", NA, "ha", "31 343"
), `3.9.2018` = c("počet", "20", "12", "bažantnice (s)", "počet", 
"14"), ...9 = c("ha", "16 239", "6 446", NA, "ha", "10 294"), 
   ...10 = c("počet", "25", "233", "bažantnice (h)", "počet", 
   "27"), ...11 = c("ha", "12 399", "60 782", NA, "ha", "12 047"
   ), ...12 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
   NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), ...13 = c(NA_character_, 
   NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
   NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", "23 456"))` converts an individual string (with spaces) into a number, but ... your data looks like you may have strings intermingled with your numbers. Can you provide an unambiguous data sample by posting `dput(head(x))` where `x` is your dataset?

Comment: it is not easy to help without a proper reproducible example, as suggested by r2evans.

Comment: @r2evans the text was too big, so I edited the post. Is it ok like this? And the head part wasn't representative, so I chose a different section.

Comment: Okay, that's a great data sample, thank you @AnnaSwade! Unfortunately, it shows what I suspected: you have text intermingled with number-like strings, so there is no way you can convert them into `numeric` (real) numbers without losing the text. That is, if you run `as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", X[[2]]))`, you'll get back `c(NA, 1496, 4255, NA, NA, 751)` with a warning, because `"po et"` (etc) cannot be converted to a number. If this is acceptable, then `X[,-1] <- lapply(X[,-1], function(z) suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", z))))` does what you want.

Comment: Said differently: in R, a vector (and a column of a `data.frame`) can contain only one *class* of object. Typical classes include `character`, `numeric`, `integer`, `logical`, etc. Mixing them will "up-class" or coerce from the simpler number-like up. This means that `c(1L, 2)` (int and float) will produce two floats, and `c(1, "2")` will produce two strings, `c("1", "2")`. For what you're likely doing with your data, there is no way around this. If you need both strings and numbers somehow, you may need to separate the string-like from the number-like into separate columns.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you very much! :) It's a lot of information to take in, but I do now understand that one column has to be 1 type of class. I'll have a further look at it tomorrow. If I have any more questions, may I ask you again?

Comment: Sure, if it still fits this question you can [edit] your question and add detail.

Comment: @r2evans If you have any spare time, would you be willing to look at the edited form of the question please?:) I have tried to make a function for this task, but I always got stuck somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247992/discussion-between-anna-swade-and-r2evans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
ischr <- sapply(dat, is.character)
dat[ischr] <- lapply(dat[ischr], function(z) ifelse(grepl("[^ 0-9]", z), z, gsub(" +", "", z)))
dat
# # A tibble: 6 x 13
#   `VÝKAZ MYSL 1-01 - SUMÁ E`   ...2    ...3    ...4   ...5  ...6  ...7  `3.9.2018`     ...9  ...10 ...11 ...12 ...13
#   <chr>                        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>          <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 "Vlastnický vztah k honitb " po et   NA      ha     po et NA    ha    po et          ha    po et ha    NA    NA   
# 2 "1. vlastní"                 1496    1511605 NA     178   NA    41911 20             16239 25    12399 NA    NA   
# 3 "2. spole enstevní"          4255    5077050 NA     24    NA    2401  12             6446  233   60782 NA    NA   
# 4  NA                          honitba NA      NA     NA    obora NA    ba antnice (s) NA    ba a~ NA    NA    NA   
# 5 "Zp sob vyu ívání honitby"   po et   NA      ha     po et NA    ha    po et          ha    po et ha    NA    NA   
# 6 "1. ve vlastní re ii"        751     NA      780487 137   NA    31343 14             10294 27    12047 NA    NA
```